# "Transition" does not transform the ul element

Tags: html, css, transform, transition

This is a simple drop down menu.

Cant understand why the animation with "transition" does not transform the ul element? I have isolated the problem in the code with **START** & **END**.

In the beginning ul has translateY(-2em), on hover translateY(0%)

```css
html {
  background: #EEEEEE;
}
.container {
  background: white;
  margin: 5% auto 0 auto;
}
.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
}
/*
////////////
////START///
////////////
*/

.menu ul li ul {
  display: none;
  transform: translateY(-2em);
  /* Why transition does not work? */
  transition: transform 300ms ease-in-out 0s;
}
.menu ul li:hover ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  margin-top: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(0%)
}
/*
////////////
////END/////
////////////
*/

.menu ul li:hover ul li:hover {
  background: #EEEEEE;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li>One
      </li>
      <li>Hover
        <ul ">
              <li>0</li>
              <li>0</li>
              <li>0</li>
              <li>0</li>
              <li>0</li>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <li>Three</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I *think* it's because the `display` and/or `position` properties are changing.. is it that you want the menu to slide down?

Comment: @Toby Yes, I want it to slide...

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't pretty, but it demonstrates that it's the `display` and `position` properties changing that prevent the transition from working.

Most commonly this is achieved using `max-height`, `opacity` and/or `visibility`.

```css
html {
  background: #EEEEEE;
}
.container {
  background: white;
  margin: 5% auto 0 auto;
}
.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
}
/*
////////////
////START///
////////////
*/

.menu ul li ul {
  transform: translateY(-2em);
  /* Why transition does not work? */
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}
.menu ul li:hover ul {
  background: white;
  margin-top: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(0%)
}
/*
////////////
////END/////
////////////
*/

.menu ul li:hover ul li:hover {
  background: #EEEEEE;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li>One
      </li>
      <li>Hover
        <ul ">
              <li>0</li>
              <li>0</li>
              <li>0</li>
              <li>0</li>
              <li>0</li>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <li>Three</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Now I see what the problem was =) Thank you a lot